# How do I create a value for Facebook:VerifyToken:User in a Facebook application using ASP.NET MVC 4 with Web Tools 2012.2?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2. I created a Facebook application under ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application and target of .Net Framework 4.5. I can create an AppId and AppSecret
through https://developers.facebook.com/apps but the application requests a value for Facebook:VerifyToken:User. Exactly how do I create one and get the application to work?

Comment: Have you get a chance to look into this : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/13/the-new-facebook-application-template-and-library-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The "Facebook:VerifyToken:User" setting in the project template is optional and is used in the UserRealtimeUpdateController. You only need to set this when your application want to support Facebook Realtime Updates. See this link for more information about the realtime updates: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

The VerifyToken is set by you when you create a realtime update subscription.

Hope this helps,

Yao

Answer (score 0):

You can use either DotNetOpenAuth or the Facebook C# SDK to authenticate against Facebook and request an access token. Take a look at the FacebookClient in DotNetOpenAuth, I've successfully used this to request an access token. You will need to pass the right scope parameter across for the permissions you need. Could you elaborate on how your app needs to interact with Facebook?

Comment: As I've already said, the Facebook project template for Web Tools 2012.2 requests the token at runtime, irrespective of how any bespoking of the application would work. Thanks for your attempt but telling me to read the SDK does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I gave a value for the Facebook:AppNamespace setting (which is supposedly optional according to the literature that I have read as well as stating so on the Facebook form). Once I did this, the problem went away.